# Execute function after gform_after_submission is completed and success response for submission

Tags: php, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

Using this https://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/article/gform_after_submission/

I have a custom function to send notifications in a loop to a set of email addresses.
I send the notification after a Gravity Form is submitted.
But seems it takes time for form submission as the success response is recieved after some time. If I remove the custom send notification function call in the gform_after_submission PHP action hook the response is much quicker.

So seems this action isn't really after form submission?

What is a way to let the form submit ie, create entry and give success response and then only process custom send notification function?
Should I use scheduled process (windows) or cronjob (linux based server)?

Code

```
add_action('gform_after_submission_19', 'send_custom_notification', 10, 2);

function send_custom_notification($entry, $form) {
    send_notification("form_submission", $form, $entry);
}
```

I guess the submission response is received only after custom function send_notification is done? Any way to do this after response from submission is received? If not guess best option would be to run a scheduled task or cron job to execute custom function?

Comment: Try with : gform_pre_submission_filter_19

Comment: No sorry, that seems to do before submission, so validation etc? I don't need that. Need to execute custom function after submission and submit response received, maybe better to store the submission, ie form and entry in a table and then run scheduled task with tracking like sent flag etc?